# Grammar and rearranging hyperbaton in 'The Rime of the Ancient Mariner'?

Tags: grammaticality, poetry

https://english.stackexchange.com/a/184742/50720 exemplifies with [The Rime of the Ancient Mariner](http://lit.genius.com/Samuel-taylor-coleridge-the-rime-of-the-ancient-mariner-in-seven-parts-from-sibylline-leaves-1817-annotated#note-2257454):

> The rock shone bright, the [kirk](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/kirk) no less,
>   　**[1.] That** stands above the rock:
>   The moonlight steeped in silentness
>   　**[2.] The steady weathercock**.
>
> And the bay was white with silent light,
>   　[3.] Till rising from the same,
>   Full many shapes, that shadows were,
>   　In crimson colours came.

1. What does **That** refer to?

2. Is **The steady weathercock** supposed also to be 'steeped in silentness'? I recognise this as poetry, but what's the phenomenon here called? Why's there no conjunction linking **The steady weathercock**?

3. How do you determine/deduce the correct (re)order of words in the 3 lines after [3.]?

Comment: I fixed your indentation in the way I believe you want it. This character might look like a normal space, but it's not. Technically, it's called Ideographic Space, also known as [Unicode U+3000](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3000/index.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That = kirk = church.

```
Moonlight = subject
steeped = transitive verb
the steady weathercock = direct object of steeped  (steady because windless or no changing winds)
```

The bay was white with silent light, till full many shapes, that were shadows, came rising in crimson colors from the same (i.e. from the bay that was white with silent light).

Compare *came running*, *came galloping*, *came hopping*, *came sledding*...

*Full* is not an adjective but an adverb (see http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/full) that modifies *many*. Very many shapes.

Comment: +1. Thank you effusively for your continual care. Would you please clarify 'full many shapes'; what noun does 'full' modify? Does this equate to 'many full shapes'?

Comment: You are welcome. Please see the addendum.

Comment: +1. Thank you effusively for your continual care. Please maintain your superlative contributions and beneficence, which I cherish.

Comment: I haven't been thanked so thoroughly since I managed to knock that asteroid off its collision course with planet Earth. :-)