# How to determine the right order of hyperbaton?

Tags: syntax, rhetoric

I thank and understand user TRomano's (effusively generous, truly  helpful) [explantion and transcription](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/37722/8712), but I still don't understand how to determine how to rearrange/reshuffle hyperbaton by myself, correctly and perfectly? How do I perceive the steps and thought processes, to reorder the original to an intellgible form/version? I ask NOT only about hyperbaton in poetry, but in any more abstruse, complex writing.

I realise that my English is rudimentary and that this question may involve years of reading hard, dense poetry, but I'm interested in the most efficient, productive solution. Given that these short passages have already troubled me enought to pose several questions, trial and error wouldn't reveal the keys needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your question implies there's a recipe for parsing poetry and complex passages that can be succinctly put into words. There really isn't.

You are reading not only modern works but passages from the 19th century and the 18th century. Yet you have been consulting *abridged* dictionaries, and in doing so, you are "bringing a knife to a gunfight" (apologies for the Americanism.) The Merriam-Webster online dictionary is adequate for most 20th century texts. But for older texts, one often must consult the big Oxford English Dictionary to ascertain the meaning(s) in use when the author was writing (ISBN 76-188038 -- available in a two-volume compact edition with very tiny print and a magnifying glass; each volume weighs about 4 kilos).

Comment: +1 That edition of the *OED* is available through links [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/739/32) on ELL, and OP has repeatedly been directed to it.

Comment: @StoneyB: Thank you. To elucidate though, I find that with these poems, my problem concerns rearrangement of the words, rather than the words themselves that I already understand? Does this affect my OP?

Comment: A dictionary that offers examples of all of the forms of a word might keep you from becoming fixed on a possible meaning that is not the most probable meaning.  It might have kept you from looking at *steeped* as intransitive, and from regarding *full* as an adjective. Your assumption that some poetic trope was involved was a direct result of your having taken *steeped* to be intransitive.